# How to place my application icon on another app's actionbar automatically in android?

Tags: android, emoji, android-sdk-2.3

I am developing Emoji app, which is suppose to appear on application's action bar like **whatsApp**.

Following is screen shoot of expected result, how can I achieve such result?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can see screen shoot(sign) ?

Comment: That screen shoot would be very usefull.

Comment: The screen shoot seems to have shot off the screen

Comment: @jvrodrigues :- please see the screen shoot

Comment: I dont see any, where is it?

Comment: Khyati, where is the screen shot? I can not see any dear.

Comment: @turtle please see my screen shoot on below link   http://oi57.tinypic.com/152kwvq.jpg

Comment: you have to set action in intent filter to make app visible in share options

Comment: @MeenalSharma which action do I need to specify?

Comment: I dont think so you can put your app icon on any other app's action bar..from my point of view its not possible.

Comment: @pratt This is screen shoot of one application which is behaving like this..Its already implemented..

Comment: @KhyatiShah Another application's icon on Whats App Action bar? Are you sure?

Comment: @KhyatiShah Just think dear, for that you have to access WhatsApp code, I mean Actionbar of WhatsApp. How can you access it. Maybe rooted phone can access I dont know.

Comment: Please download Emojidom app from play store...You can experience it..

Answer (score 0):

set this in the manifest for that activity

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: @Khyati Shah try this

Comment: add this in your launcher activity